# Order by "multiplication" in code igniter query builder

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I got the following tables in my database

```
Product(product_id,title,sale_price,tax_id)

Tax(Tax_id,label,rate)
```

I'm trying to show a list of products ordered by product.sale_price*tax.rate

How can I achieve that with Code Igniter

For the moment, my code looks like this :

```
$this->db->order_by('sale_price', 'asc');
$this->db->get('product');
```

And I tried to do something like this in SQL, but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM product inner join tax on product.tax_id = tax.tax_id ORDER BY (product.sale_price*tax.rate) ASC
```

Thank you.

Comment: something like SELECT 
    sale_price * rate as 'Total' ORDER BY Total

Answer (score 3):

Try below query

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->select('p.sale_price*t.rate as sortable_column');
$this->db->order_by('sortable_column', 'asc');
$this->db->join('tax t', 't.tax_id = p.tax_id');
$this->db->get('product p')->result_array();
```

Comment: I got the following error: `Unknown column 'product.sale_price*tax.rate' in 'field list`

Comment: give your table structures.

Comment: I wrote it bellow

Comment: i have updated answer. copy answered query and check now.

Comment: The following message is due to missing "sql quotes" because the generated query is something like: 

 `'p.sale_price*t.rate'`

but should be

``p`.`sale_price` * `t`.`rate``