# I am trying to check current date with date-range of database, but getting issue with codeigniter model query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to check current date with date-range of database.. but getting issue with codeigniter model query.

My code snippet- codeigniter model function:

```
public function chkCoupCode($coupon_code)
{       
    $tod_dt = date('Y-m-d');
    $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `tbl_coupons` `cc` LEFT JOIN `tbl_coupons_validity` `ccv` ON `cc`.`coupons_id` = `ccv`.`coupons_id` WHERE `coupon_code` = '".$coupon_code."' AND `cc`.`status` = '1' AND `cc`.`is_active` = 'Active' AND (`ccv`.`valid_from` >= '".$tod_dt."' OR `ccv`.`valid_to` <= '".$tod_dt."') AND `ccv`.`status` = '1' AND `ccv`.`is_active` = 'Active'");

    $result = $this->db->get('tbl_coupons cc');

    if($result->num_rows())
        return $result->result_array();
    else
        return array();
}
```

I want to check that current date exists between range means (current date exists in valid_from and valid_to database columns)..

please let me know the changes to implement it perfectly

[image]

[image]

Comment: use active record query.

Comment: will you plz elaborate

Comment: what issue you are facing?

Comment: use query like https://stackoverflow.com/a/53259188/6309457

Comment: I think you can use AND in the place of OR  `ccv`.`valid_from` >= '".$tod_dt."'  AND `ccv`.`valid_to` <= '".$tod_dt."'

Comment: @Sarfaraz thoogh not giving proper results

Comment: @DevsiOdedra please suggest me query change for proper results

Comment: @AnjaliPatil for that please give both table structure.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra provided.. plz check

Comment: @DevsiOdedra please check the images

Comment: @AnjaliPatil ok checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
public function chkCoupCode($coupon_code = 0)
    {

        $currentDate = date('d-m-Y');
        $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate));
        $this->db->select("cv.coupons_validity_id, cv.coupons_id, c.coupon_code, c.coupon_title, c.discount_percentage,c.is_flat, cv.valid_from, cv.valid_to, cv.status, cv.is_active",FALSE);
        if($coupon_code){
            $this->db->where('c.coupon_code',$coupon_code);

        }
        $this->db->where('cv.status',1);
        $this->db->where('cv.is_active','Active');
        $this->db->where('c.status',1);
        $this->db->where('c.is_active','Active');

        $this->db->where('cv.valid_from<=',$currentDate);
        $this->db->where('cv.valid_to>=',$currentDate);

        $this->db->join('tbl_coupons c', 'c.coupons_id = cv.coupons_id');
        $this->db->order_by('cv.valid_from','desc');
        $result = $this->db->get('tbl_coupons_validity cv');
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        if($result->num_rows()){
            return $result->result_array();
        }
        else
            return array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one and tell me its the result you want or need chages.

```
$this->db->where( "(tcv.valid_from >= '".$tod_dt."' OR tcv.valid_to <= '".$tod_dt."')", NULL, FALSE );
$this->db->where('tcv.status', 1);
$this->db->where('tcv.is_active', 'Active');
$this->db->where('tc.status', 1);
$this->db->where('tc.is_active', 'Active');
$this->db->where('tc.coupon_code', $coupon_code);
$this->db->join('tbl_coupons_validity tcv', 'tcv.coupons_id = tc.coupons_id', 'left');
$data = $this->db->get('tbl_coupons tc')->result_array();

print_r($data);
```

Comment: sorry.. not giving proper results. issue is in date-comparison statement.. plz help me for that

Comment: @AnjaliPatil plz tell me what result you get and what result you expected?

paste here results

Comment: @AnjaliPatil also plz share in valid_from and valid_to column have which type of date. like oly date or date and time both.

Answer (score 0):

Just add date(column_name) 
eg date(`ccv`.`valid_from`) >= '".$tod_dt."' OR date(`ccv`.`valid_to`) <= '".$tod_dt."').

I think this will work